# SXA How to create site using wizard

Tags: sxa

I tried to create a new SXA site but do not see the "Site" insert option on the `Site Folder` parent item. When I try to create it by navigating to the branch template `/sitecore/templates/Branches/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Scaffolding/Site` I get the basic site structure, but do not get the SPE wizard that I was expecting, described [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_accelerator/setting_up_and_configuring/configuring/create_a_tenant_and_a_site).

Am I expected to create site, or tennant, -specific templates before creating a site, or is it ok to just use the OOTB templates defined in `/sitecore/templates/Foundation/Experience Accelerator/Multisite`?

**Edit**

I figured out why my Sitecore instance did not have the relevant insert options for the Tennant Folder, Tenant, Site Folder templates. I installed my instance using SIM which did not respect the dependency on SPE. Although I installed SPE *afterwards* it seems you must install it *before* SXA in order for everything to work correctly.

Comment: Thanks for the updated edit, I had similar issue. I missed installing the SPE before installing the SXA.
However, just after installing the SPE everything started working.
Noticed that the order is not important but SPE is need for SXA to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After you create a new *Tenant* you should see a new context menu for creating a site.

[image: Wizard]

If the insert option does not appear on the *Tenant* item then there may be an issue with the install.

There may also be an issue with the insert options for the *Site Folder*. Try to run the wizard on the parent and then move the tree.

In my install I do see the wizard (1.4).

[image]

Comment: My problem was that I did not get these insert options by default. I'm using version 1.6 if that makes any difference. I don't know if I need to install SPE after installing SXA, or if SXA has everything it needs from the single package. I understood how it _should_ work, but was hoping to find out how I can fix this myself. I don't think these insert options are simple branch templates as they launch a wizard. I'm wondering what I need to do to hack it back into a working state.

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this same issue while working with `SXA 1.9` and `Sitecore 9.2`.
Then, I re-checked my installations. By mistake, I installed `Sitecore PowerShell Extension WDP 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2`, instead of `Sitecore PowerShell Extension 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2`.

Please check your installations as well. Install `Sitecore PowerShell Extension 5.0 for Sitecore 9.2` and it will work correctly.

**Note:** - To check if Powershell Extension is installed correctly, open your Sitecore instance and check if Powershell Console and Powershell Toolbox are showing as in below image -

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, You have to create the Tenant by right click on Content and insert the Tenant, when you do that SXA will run some command/scripts to create your project under `/sitecore/templates/Project` folder, where you will find the bunch of all predefined templates of SXA..

As per Helix fundamental, foundation is the base, so once you create the Tenant then check the templates of your Project folder under `/sitecore/templates/Project`, you will find all the Foundation multisite templates in base of specific templates. SXA is managing things internally, when you follow its process. So if you follow the proper site creation process as per SXA then only you will get the correct configurations at the end.

Answer (score 0):

After installing SXA go to `content item > right-click >` it will provide the options to create `Tenant Folder/Tenant > After that right-click on Tenant >` It will provide the option to create site/site folder.