# SXA How is the create site wizard invoked

Tags: sxa

Following from a [previous question about site / tennant creation in SXA](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10239/sxa-how-to-create-site-using-wizard) I now want to understand how/where the insert options are defined which invoke the new Tenant / new Site wizard.

This screenshot shows the insert options on the content items:
[image]
Tenant Folder is defined as an insert option on the standard values of the Tennant Folder template. However, Tennant is not and I cannot figure out where this is set up?

This is the Tennant Folder template's standard values item with the insert options dialog displayed. Notice that only Tennant Folder is here.
[image]

Also the Insert Rules is blank so its not defined here either.
[image]

This is not stopping me working, I just want to understand how this is set up!

Comment: SPE supports adding insert options. Is there an SPE script module with that bundled with SXA? https://doc.sitecorepowershell.com/content-editor.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is managed through the Rules only, if the specific rules satisfied then the related Power shell script will get executed. Please find below screen for you reference.Path to the specific item is `/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Scaffolding/Content Editor/Insert Item`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can find it in the sitecore powershell Script library

The scripts are stored at:

`/sitecore/system/Modules/PowerShell/Script Library/SXA/SXA - Scaffolding/Functions/Scaffolding/Site`

Please see the images below. There are `Powershell scripts` which are performing various functions. Creating site, removing site, etc

[image]