# How the Insert Options for a custom modules parent are invoked

Tags: sxa

We try to extend the sxa navigation with a link item that should be an extension of the navigation. With this link item, we named it "Navigation Link", we want to extend the navigation with external links or anchor links. The Link should be a part of the pages "Insert Options", similar to the Redirect Item.

[image]

Where are the SXA Insert Options (e.g for the redirect item) configured? We don't find it.

The Insert Options should be a part of the site/tenant setup.
If an adminstrator would create a new site, the page item should have the "Navigation Link" insert option.

The answer in [SXA How is the create site wizard invoked](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/sxa-how-is-the-create-site-wizard-invoked) doesnt solve the problem.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Insert Options for a custom module are managed through the [scaffolding actions](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/19/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/add-modules-to-site-and-tenant-scaffolding.html).

We extend our Site Setup with a "Edit Site Item", named "Navigation Link - Home".
This Item adds the "Insert Option" to a specified template.

[image]

After creating a new site, the home item of the site contains the desired insert option.

[image]

#### Additional

because of the page or home templates are stored within the Templates/Project/[My Tenant] folder, the Insert Options have to configured in the Tenant Setup

[image]